# How to change order of menu items

Tags: menus

How can I change the ordering of menu items -- for example to make 'Wordfruit Copywriters' appear before 'How can you sell more of your product?' here: http://richardclunan.com/

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to appearance -> menus section. Here you can create menus, add menu items and drag them around to place it to your desired place.

Alternatively, you can set up the menu order of a page. Just click edit page and you will see the menu order it should be under **Page attribute** section.

Answer (score 0):

From your Wordpress dashboard, go to `Pages`. Click `Quick Edit` and change the `Order` parameter on all of the pages to reflect the order you want.

Answer (score -1):

Go to APPEARANCE and then MENUS and int that area it allows you to drop and drag items to reorder the menu bar and the menu which appears on a smart phone. It’s very simple and much quicker than reordering all the pages (which I’ve done by the way … but it didn’t work for me).

Comment: What does this add to the already accepted answer?